# About Copying Files

Tags: file, text, cmd, copy

I want to copy some files to same destination.

Files which will be copied are listed in a text file.

So, how to read file list from text file and copy via using cmd 
command?

I tried this command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (foo.txt) do copy "%%L" new_folder
```

Similar question was asked in this website, I know that. When I use this command, files will be copied; but folders which include these files won't be copied.

I want to copy files with their directories.

What should I do? (Sorry for my awful English.)

Comment: `copy` is not very smart. Use `xcopy /?` or `robocopy /?`

Answer (score 0):

You use %%L in a batchfile and %L when typing interactivly.

Your command, depending on other factors, should have a path specified for new_folder.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.


.
--
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ,I have solved my problem via searching another cmd command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filelist.txt) do echo F|xcopy "-Source root folder-\%%i" "-Destination folder-\%%i" /i /z /y
```

In spite of the fact that I have solved my problem myself, thanks guys for your helps.

I appreciate it too much!